# cefsharp JSB how to open a new Form?

Tags: cefsharp

I use this

```
 public partial class Main : Form
 {
     public Main()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         InitBrowser();
     }
     public void InitBrowser(){
          ..........
          ceflink = new ScriptCallbackManager(this, cefBrowser);
          ceflink.show_video += Ceflink_show_video;
          cefBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("cefBrower", ceflink, isAsync: true, options: BindingOptions.DefaultBinder);
          ..........
     }
     private void Ceflink_show_video(string _ip, int _whtype)
     {
         new VideoPlayer("192.168.8.100").Show();
     }

}

 class ScriptCallbackManager
 {
     public string openvideo(string ip, int xby) {
         show_video.Invoke("192.168.8.100", 43);
         return "ok";
     }
 }
```

register an instance with the JavaScriptObjectRepository.
I want open a new Form by using javascript 
in ScriptCallbackManager class have method openvideo `show_video.Invoke();`

But he doesn't seem to work well. The new Form can be opened, but it's UI cannot be operated, and the mouse is busy.

Can you provide some examples to help me?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to open your form on the UI thread. Not on the thread pool which is what's happening based on the example you've provided.

Comment: This is the theory, but I don't know what to do. In the end, I had no choice but to use Win32api's PostMessage

Comment: What makes you think `PostMessage` is required? Just use `BeginInvoke` to post back to the ui thread.

Comment: I have used BeginInvoke, but the new Form flashes

Comment: Confirm that it works just with a regular button click. You'll need to provide an updated example if you require further assistance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, this problem can also be seen as an inter-process communication problem. PostMessage runs very well. I need to use it in other places in this project.

Comment: I don't see how it's an interprocess communication problem as you are only using a single process. The example you've provided is incomplete so I cannot really say anything. If you have a solution that works then go with it.